# redux-socket.io/dist/index.js: Couldn't find preset \"es2015\"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I installed "redux-socket.io" and when I run the app again it shows and error like this:

error: bundling failed: "TransformError: ../../../../node_modules/redux-socket.io/dist/index.js: Couldn't find preset \"es2015\"

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using babel, you have to install [**babel-preset-es2015**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) and use it in your `.babelrc`, e.g:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Hope that this can help :)